# Saber si se encuentra una palabra en una cadena en php

Tags: php, array, string

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
$msg = 'Hola :1: quetal??, :2:';
$emoticones = array(':1:',':2:',':3:');
$cntidademoticon = explode(' ', $msg);
foreach ($cntidademoticon as $string) {
    echo '<br>'.$string.'<br>';
}
```

Lo que estoy buscando es contar las cantidades de palabras que coinciden con la variable `$emoticones`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esto se puede hacer fácilmente con la función de PHP `strpos()`.
Los datos de entrada son primero el pajar (en tu caso, la variable `$msg`) y la aguja (el arreglo), te dejo el siguiente ejemplo:

```
<?php 
    $msg = 'Hola :1: quetal??, :2:';
    $emoticones = array(':1:',':2:',':3:');
    $contador = 0;
    $lenght = count($emoticones);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $lenght; $i++){
            if(strpos($msg, $emoticones[$i]) !== false){
                $contador++;
            }
        }
echo "Número de coincidencias: ". $contador;
?>
```

---

Para el caso de que queramos saber el número de veces que se repite una misma cadena dentro de otra, usaremos la función de PHP `substr_count()`, es el mis procedimiento, solo que ahora crearemos un auxiliar que guarde el número de coincidencias y se sume con el acumulador (y en caso de que no existe, se suma 0, por eso es importante inicializarlo al inicio del ciclo en 0):

```
<?php 
    $msg = 'Hola :2: quetal??, :2: :1:';
    $emoticones = array(':1:',':2:',':3:');
    $acumulador = 0;
    $aux = 0;
    $lenght = count($emoticones);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $lenght; $i++){
            $aux = 0;
            $aux = substr_count($msg, $emoticones[$i]);
            $acumulador = $acumulador + $aux;
        }
echo "Número de coincidencias: ". $acumulador;
?>
```

EDIT: Cabe aclarar que el acumulador es solamente si se usará un `array` de `strings` para buscar dentro de otro `string`

Comment: Perfecto es lo que buscaba, pero si se repite por ejemplo en el mensaje colocan dos veces :2: me contaria 1 solamente que crees que podria hacer? Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Edite mi respuesta. :)

Comment: Perfecto. eres un astro. Muchisimas gracias jeje